# Python2.7 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, mojibake

I am currently using python 2.7 and doing web scraping on a Chinese website.

How to convert unicode below into a string?

Simple str() function does not work and states
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: ordinal not in range(128)

Thanks in advance,

```
    u'\n\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe6\xb7\xb1\xe5\x9c\xb3\n'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string was already encoded, so it should be a bytes object not a unicode object.  Try and solve that problem instead.  i.e. the `repr` of your scraped data should be looking like this:

```
'\n\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe6\xb7\xb1\xe5\x9c\xb3\n'
```

not like this:

```
u'\n\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe6\xb7\xb1\xe5\x9c\xb3\n'
```

To recover the Chinese text from the unicode object, you can jump to bytes and back:

```
>>> text = u'\n\xe4\xb8\xad\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe6\xb7\xb1\xe5\x9c\xb3\n'
>>> print text.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')

中国深圳
```